# Can't get theme attribute references to work in android

Tags: android, themes

I'm very new (second day!) to android and working my way through the dev guide. There, it says that you can reference attributes inside the current theme from your XML by using the form "?...", for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText id="text"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="?android:textDisabledColor"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

If I try to build this, I just get "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '?android:textDisabledColor')

Given that this seems pretty basic stuff, and yet I can't find any references to similar problems elsewhere, I must be missing something obvious or misunderstanding something simple. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **textDisabledColor** exists anymore - at least not in the newer SDKs which is probably why it can't be found. Try **textColorSecondary** instead - e.g.

`android:textColor="?android:attr/android:textColorSecondary"`

Unfortunately I cant figure out if theres a specific disabled color.  I came across the site below which seems to define the default theme: [See this link for definition of default theme](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 0):

try `android:textColor="?android:attr/textDisabledColor"`

Comment: That's still not working, I'm afraid. To let you know where I was starting from with this, it's the basic Hello, Android application in the dev guide.